# QGIS crashes when selecting symbols

Tags: qgis, symbology, debugging

I am using QGIS version 2.14.1 (Essen). I can open it no problem and load shapefiles correctly. However, when I go in the file properties and select "style"/ "unique symbols", the system crashes and the following error message appears:

*qgis bin.exe has stopped working*

I have uninstalled QGIS and reinstalled it, tried system restore but to no avail, the problem keeps occuring. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Now very little is working... EVen when I try to open the prpoerties of the file it crashes....

Comment: What is "unique symbols"?

Comment: @Joseph in the properties of the layer, then "style", you have a list of styles you can choose. The problem occurs when I click on "symboles uniques" in french, as I' m using QGIS in french. I guess in english its "unic symbols"....